# Flipkart Seller API "DEPENDENT_SYSTEM_CALL_FAILED" error

Tags: java, spring-boot, e-commerce, flipkart-api

We are working on flipkart integration and facing issue in few of API which is as below.
Here we are trying to mark a shipment as "ready_to_dispatch" so that we can download the invoice and label.

**API**: https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v3/shipments/dispatch

**Request Body**:

```json
{
    "shipmentIds": [
        "actualShipmentId"
    ],
    "locationId": "acutalLocationId"
}
```

**Response Body**:

```json
{
    "shipments": [
        {
            "shipmentId": "actualShipmentId",
            "status": "FAILURE",
            "errorCode": "DEPENDENT_SYSTEM_CALL_FAILED",
            "errorMessage": "A call to dependent system failed. Please retry after some time"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there anyone who can suggest something on this?

Initially i thought it was due to that as a customer I didn't accepted the order from flipkart over call. But now after the confirming the order as well I'm not able to mark it.
Is there anything which I'm missing.